# how to exclude PHPUnit based functional tests from runnning?

Tags: 8, testing

I am trying to run only unit test for my custom module.

`./vendor/bin/phpunit -c ./web/core ./web/modules/custom/testing_example --testsuite=unit` .
But I keep getting the following error:

There were 2 errors:

`1) Drupal\Tests\testing_example\Kernel\ExampleFixtureManagementTest::testNodeCreation
Exception: There is no database connection so no tests can be run. You must provide a SIMPLETEST_DB environment variable to run PHPUnit based functional tests outside of run-tests.sh. See https://www.drupal.org/node/2116263#skipped-tests for more information.`

I only want to run PhpUnit tests and not functional/browser tests.

Answer (score 0):

Since those tests are grouped by namespace/directory, you can just pass the respective path to phpunit, simply add `tests/src/Unit` to your existing path.

Comment: I want to run all the unit tests in the custom modules directory I'm not sure if you mean I can add it as an extra path parameters or this as path/to/module/tests/src/Unit?

Comment: I was wondering about that, but your question specifically mentiones a single module and provides the path to that ;) Not sure if combining testsuite and a path is the problem, I would suggest you create your own phpunit.xml based on the example, adjust the include path and leave out the path in the command

Answer (score 0):

To run only certain tests in phpunit, append `--filter` (https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/textui.html) in your phpunit call whether directly in cli or in an IDE phpunit config.

To filter to only Unit tests *across all modules* but exclude Functional and Kernel tests, you can pass in something that matches the well-structured Drupal tests path like @Berdir was getting at like `--filter Unit`.

I suspect there's a more specific way to narrow it down like `--filter tests/src/Unit` but I didn't figure it out.  I assume one can also combine filters to pick and chose among Unit and Kernel, for instance, but I also didn't play with that. :)